# jquery get value of select

Tags: jquery, html-select

I am having problems trying to get the value of a select box with jquery

```
<select id='form[1]' name='form[1]'>
    <option val='1'>1</option>
    <option val='2'>2</option>
</select>
```

I've tried:

```
$('#form[1]').val()
```

and:

```
$('#form\\[1\\]').val()
```

But no luck

This ended up working for me i'd post it as an answer but i can't for 8 hours

```
var num = $(".forms").attr('name', 'form[1]');

$(num[0]).val();
```

Thank you for all your help

Comment: Worth nothing that that `id` is invalid in HTML4.  I believe it's fine in html5.

Comment: I noticed you updated your question to say that the provided answers don't work.  This fiddle shows that they do, perhaps you have some other issue?  http://jsfiddle.net/Ba4uq/

Answer (score 6):

Try `$('#form\\[1\\]').val()`. You need to escape the `[]`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with the selector. The brackets have to be escaped: `$('#form\\[1\\]').val()`

As an aside, the convention I've seen from many frameworks is to make the id something `form-1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the element.  I think this is easier to write than escaping the `[]`.

```
$('select[id="form[1]"]')
```

Comment: But this is probably not as efficient as an ID lookup...note, I have no empirical evidence to back this up, but it sounds right.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: It may be slower, but I think it's nicer to write than `\\[1\\]`. :-P

Comment: @Rocket I'll give you that, but on a large page this could be a reasonable difference in efficiency.  I guess at least use `select[id=...` to help jquery out a bit.  Personally I'd change my `id` to something nicer...